# PHP if then else for all URL starting with this domain else do something else

Tags: php, html, if-statement, joomla

I want an example in php with if then else, that is

lets say a variable have a value containing URL

so

if the URL starts with a cetrain URL www.blabla.com/... then do something

else

if the URL start with www.whateverurl.com/... then do something else ,,

I hope its clear enough Guys, please some help,

My PHP code with the embedded HTML is like that. How can I avoid all the cases and have just one if and one else and not have `elseif`?

```
<?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?></br>

   <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "http://www.blabla.com/index.php/article?id=3200") : ?></br>                

         <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "http://www.blabla.com/index.php/article?id=1508") : ?></br>

         <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "http://www.blabla.com/index.php/article?id=1840") : ?></br>

         <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a> 

        <?php elseif ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() == "http://www.blabla.com/index.php/article?id=2541") : ?></br>

         <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="readon"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>       

 <?php else : ?></br>

        <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="modal" rel="{size: {x: 1024, y: 550}, handler:'iframe'}"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>           

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you all and any ideas or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: I cannot understand your question what you are exactly expecting

Comment: I think using joomla you can use the 'JRequest::getVar('id');' to get the $_GET['id'] and then use a multi condition 'if' statement.

Comment: Thank you wayzz for the answer

Comment: I m sorry Nes but all the people respond correclty to my question ,, i think its clear enough the question thats why so many peope respond with an answer,,,  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch()` statement.

```
    switch ($item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl()) {
        case "http://www.blabla.com/index.php/article?id=3200":
            echo "<a href=". $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl()." class='readon'><span>". rc_e('READ_MORE'). "</span></a>";
            break;
        case "http://www.blabla.com/index.php/article?id=1508":
            echo "<a href=". $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl()." class='readon'><span>". rc_e('READ_MORE')."</span></a>";
            break;
        ...
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Thank you wayzz for the response, but this doesnt make any diffrence to me, i just dont want to use so many cases,,, when everything start with www.blabla.com the action is always the same... for all the rest url.. is another action,,,, the switch is the same with the if -elseif-else,,, i want to have only if-else .....

Comment: I have posted another answer see if it is correct. Please excuse me If it is mistaken as I am not familiar to Joomla. If incorrect please tell me and I'll remove the answer.

Comment: Thank you again wayzz for the effort and for the quick response,,, yeas its an approach that would work,,,, but unfortunatelly i m looking for a global solution that would not have to go back in case of more added id's,, i m looking for a statement that would catch all the url's starting from a certain www.blabla,com/... no matter is the id ,,,, just to look on the main domain.... i hope u understand ,, ,and once again thank you for the answer,,,

Comment: Can i please know what $this->getPrimaryLink() and $this->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl() print please?

Comment: yeas it grabs the url assigned in the RokSprocket module in the backed,,, ,, so if this starts with http://www.blabla.com/.... then make one action,, else if this starts with http://www.whateverelse.com/.... do something else...

Comment: you want the main domain and use that in the if statement? Well you can maybe use the explode() function and then compare the first item in the array which would be your link/domain

Comment: I have edited my last answer. See if you can work something out which is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the explode() function to get the first part of your url.

```
<?php 

    $url= $item->getPrimaryLink(); // www.blabla.com/index.php?id=123 <- The slash would be your divider in this case.
    $url_ex= explode("/", $url); 

    // So now you have
    //$url_ex[0] = 'www.blabla.com';
    //$url_ex[1] = 'index.php?id=123';
?>



 <?php if ($item->getPrimaryLink()) : ?></br>
        <?php if ($url_ex[0] == 'www.blabla.com'){

            echo "<a href=". $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl()." class='readon'><span>". rc_e('READ_MORE'). "</span></a>";
    }
 <?php else : ?></br>

        <a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" class="modal" rel="{size: {x: 1024, y: 550}, handler:'iframe'}"><span><?php rc_e('READ_MORE'); ?></span></a>           

<?php endif; ?>
```

I think you can use something similar to this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php